# Looking to have my worked check on a calculus series question

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series, taylor-expansion

I am trying to determine if the Taylor series of $f(y) = y^{-\frac{1}{3}}$ about $y=1$ converges absolutely at $y = 2$.

I am calculating the Taylor series as $$f(y) = 1 + a_1 (y-1) + a_2 (y-1)^2 + \dots$$ where for $n \geq 1$, $$a_n = \frac{(-1)^n}{n!3^n} \prod_{j=1}^n \left( 3j - 2 \right).$$

Does this calculation using the Root Test check out?

$$\sqrt[n]{\left| a_n \right|} \leq \left( \frac{(3n - 2)^n}{n!3^n} \right)^{\frac{1}{n}} = \frac{3n - 2}{3\sqrt[n]{n!}} \longrightarrow 0 \text{ as } n \longrightarrow \infty$$

Thank you for helping out.

Answer (score 1):

The limit of $\dfrac{3n-2}{3\sqrt[n]{n!}}$ is not $0$, since $\sqrt[n]{n!}\le n$.

For this series, the ratio test is easier to use.

**Remark:** To settle the question of absolute convergence at the point $y=2$, replace $3j-2$ everywhere except for $j=1$ by $3j-3$. That decreases the absolute value of the terms. Now you will get some nice cancellation, and will be basically looking at the harmonic series.

Comment: Isn't the ratio test inconclusive?  Since it gives $(3(n+1) - 2)/(n+1)3$ which goes to $1$?

Comment: The ratio test gives us the radius of convergence. It does not settle convergence at $2$. Neither does the root test in this case, the limit of the $n$-th root will turn out to be $1$, after a more painful calculation.

Comment: In your actual problem about convergence at $2$, you do not need to worry at all about the radius of convergence. Your question did not ask how to solve the problem, so I will only give a hint. Except at $n=1$, replace $3j-2$ by $3j-3$.

Comment: Would you mind at least telling me if it converges or diverges?  Sorry for the laziness...

Comment: About the Wolfram calculation, it says the terms have limit $0$. As you know, terms having limit $0$ does not imply convergence.  The series does not converge absolutely at $2$.

Comment: (Yeah, I realized that, that's why I deleted the comment.)

Comment: When I replace with $3j - 3$ I get that the series is $\geq \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n(n-1)}{2n!}$ which converges (Wolfram).  So that doesn't tell me anything, right?

Comment: Look at your product of the $3j-2$, which is $(1)(4)(7)\dots(3n-2)$. Replace by $(1)(3)(6)\cdots(3n-3)$. There is cancellation with the factorial, and the $3$'s. I think we get $\frac{1}{3}\cdot \frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: It does appear that way.  So it diverges.  Thank you for your time and patience.

Comment: You are welcome. I did not say it diverges. It does not converge absolutely.

Comment: Right, that's what I meant.  I have to admit that, rather shamefully, I posed this question as one of calculus, when it really arose while I was trying to solve another problem.  Since the series does not converge absolutely, I am still stuck on my main problem, which I posted here, in case you have any interest in taking a look:
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1616625/show-int-pi-infty-fracdxx2-left-sin2x-right1-3-is-finite-u

Comment: Maybe I can look at it tomorrow, it is very late here.

Comment: Ok!  Thanks again.